# php strpos ignoring character

Tags: php, html

I am trying to parse a string but what I get returned is incorrect , I am trying to extract just the question mark from doc=? and slide=?, but instead I get

> **doc id:**&doc=9729&slide=214679&#doc=9729&slide=21
>
> **slide id:**&slide=214679&#doc=9729

string :

> http:/securefinder.com/ajax_query/delimiter.aspx?q=LNG&f=1.1&doc=9729&slide=214679&#doc=9729&slide=214679&

It seems it does not accept & as the delimiting character.

```
 <?php

    function from_to($string, $from, $to) {
        //Calculate where each substring is found inside of $string
        $pos_from = strpos($string, $from);
        $pos_to   = strpos($string, $to);


        //The function will break if $to appears before $from, throw an exception.
        if ($pos_from > $pos_to) {

        }

        return substr(
            $string,
            $pos_from, //From where the $from starts (first character of $from)
            $pos_to - $pos_from + strlen($to) //To where the $to ends. (last character of $to)
        );
    }

    $str = "http:/securefinder.com/ajax_query/delimiter.aspx?q=LNG&f=1.1&doc=9729&slide=214679&#doc=9729&slide=214679&";


         $doc_id = from_to($str, 'doc=', '&');
          $slide_id = from_to($str, 'slide=', '&');


echo 'doc id:' . $doc_id ;
echo 'slide id:'. $slide_id;



    ?>
```

Comment: Just use [`parse_str($str, $variables)`](http://us.php.net/parse_str) instead of inventing your own parser.

Comment: @Dcoder thanks didn't know about parse_str will try it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [`prase_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to break up the url and then use [`parse_str()`](http://us.php.net/parse_str) on the query result to first break up your query by `#`, the results of that by `&`, and finally the results of that by `=`.

This way you don't need to write your own parsing logic.  From this you will get a nice array to manipulate instead of trying to figure out how to manipulate your string.

Answer (score 0):

Try, using **preg_match**

```
$str = "http:/securefinder.com/ajax_query/delimiter.aspx?q=LNG&f=1.1&doc=9729&slide=214679&#doc=9729&slide=214679&";

preg_match("/doc=(.*?)&/i", $str, $d);    
preg_match("/slide=(.*?)&/i", $str, $s);

$doc_id   =  $d[1];
$slide_id =  $s[1];

echo 'doc id:' . $doc_id ;
echo 'slide id:'. $slide_id;
```

Comment: While `preg_match()` has its uses, sometimes using it for simple tasks such as this is just overkill.